# How to Force STARTTLS on Outlook and other clients

Tags: email, outlook, starttls

I am currently writing an essay about securing E-Mails. Now I'm at the point where I want to know if it´s possible to force `STARTTLS` in connections via `SMTP` or `POP3/IMAP` from the clients' side. I know I can configure the client so it uses `STARTTLS` but I don't know if I can force it.

Background of this idea will be that no downgrade attack will be possible without noticing.

Does anyone know if there is such an implementation in circulation for Outlook (Or other mail agents)?